# Rearrangement of Laplacian function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, decreasing-rearrangements

It is known that  if $\nabla u$,  in the sense of distributions, is a function that satisfies $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}<\infty$, then its Symmetric decreasing rearrangement $\nabla u^\ast$ satisfies
$$
\|\nabla u^\ast\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
$$
Is there some inequality for the higher-order derivative of $u$, for example is there any relation between $\|\Delta u^\ast\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ and $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint see that $$\Delta u=div(\nabla u)$$ Apply the given inequality  first for each partial derivative then on the gradient.

Comment: Can you provide the details? (And the OP is probably gone for good since this post is one year old)